# Does Capybara has_selector? wait like

Tags: ruby, capybara

When I use Capybara's has_selector? does it wait and retry to try to find the dom node like the find() method does? I'm not finding any useful information in the docs below. I'm interested in the answer, but I'm really more interested in how I would deduce that information from the ruby docs (which always give me problems navigating).

http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_selector%3F-instance_method

http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders#find-instance_method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. If you look at the `assert_selector` source, it calls `synchronize`.

http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Base#synchronize-instance_method

"Show source" is your friend, most rendered docs will have it. And then there is always the actual source code. Which, many times, will trump any rendered documentation.